# What is the difference between make and make -j5?

Tags: opencv, makefile, gnu-make

I have been trying to include OpenCV extra modules by following the link [OpenCV Contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib). After solving several errors obtained during the **cmake** command, when I did **make -j5**, it stopped giving error

`[ 27%] Built target IlmImf
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

When I ran simple **make** command, it started compiling and making the targets what happens when we make OpenCV in the build directory. 
I again then tried **make -j5** but this time I received some other error while make again compiled.

I wanted to know what's the differnce between **make** and **make -j5** !!

Thanks in advance for the reply !!

Comment: Not sure why they gave you a negative vote, this is a valid questions that helped me. So +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

> -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs] Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If there  is  more than one -j option, the last one is effective. If the -j option is given without an argument, make  will  not  limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously.

This is from `man make`. Errors are the same, but compilation process can encounter them in different order